# Wrap the highlight text with span element in JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highlight

This my code but there is an error if you override the highlighted text.
The error is:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on
>   'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.

**JS**

```
function surroundSelection() {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute('class', 'hlt')

  if (window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
      range.surroundContents(span);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to deal with the problem? The error is fairly clear: The selection includes parts of a node that isn't a text node, and so `surroundContents` itself can't do the job. You have to look at what's in the range and deal with how to highlight the selection cross-element. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/surroundContents) even flags this up: *"An exception will be thrown, however, if the Range splits a non-Text node with only one of its boundary points."* So you'll need more than one span in that case.

Comment: yes i dont have idea on how how it can pass to element and override the highlight. yes i need more span element for that. hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: Working through it yourself will be the best help. Otherwise, this is just a "please write this for me" request, not a question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
function surroundSelection() {       
    var selection= window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    span.setAttribute('class', 'hlt')
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
}
```

Comment: it's correct. but when we have multi paragraph this is not work correctly.